# Populating gallery from an array using an ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I am trying to populate a gallery using a custom arrayadapter. I am trying to use the oudated gallery method where the pic selected is shown enlarged after it is clicked using Onclick. Right now it populates but all images are fully enlarged and scrollable. The toast message in the onClick is working but the gallery is not.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);

    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
    Resources res = ctx.getResources();

    String[] options = res.getStringArray(R.array.image_names);
    TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);

    gallery.setAdapter(new ArrayImageAdapter(ctx, R.layout.main,
            options, icons));

    TypedArray imageIDs = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
        int position, long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //---display the images selected---
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
            imageView.setImageResource(position);
        }
    });
}



public class ArrayImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private String[] mStrings;
    private TypedArray mIcons;

    private int mViewResourceId;

    public ArrayImageAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId,
            String[] strings, TypedArray icons) {
        super(ctx, viewResourceId, strings);

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        mStrings = strings;
        mIcons = icons;

        mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mStrings.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mStrings[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        iv.setImageDrawable(mIcons.getDrawable(position));

        TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tv.setText(mStrings[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The reason why your image doesn't show is because change `imageView.setImageResource(position);` to `imageView.setImageDrawable(imageIDs.getDrawable(position));`

Comment: @AmulyaKhare I think the problem has more to do with the layout. Right now the images show. They are getting pulled from the array in my resources just fine. But they are getting populated fully expanded. I want them to show as the outdated gallery class would display them. With small scrollable thumbnails across the top. Then once clicked, the image selected should be shown large. Just like in this example. http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/creating-image-gallery/  I want them Shown just like in this example.

Comment: `imageView.setImageResource(position);` this is not going to work, the position is not a resource, it is the index in the array

Answer (score 0):

The methods of the imageView you're going to want to use in the getView method of your ArrayAdapter are **ImageView.setScaleType** and **ImageView.setLayoutParams**. This will shrink your images.

imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));

In here it explains LayoutParams a little more: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)